# Private keystore for truststore with client Axis2 stub

Tags: java, apache-axis

I need to call a webservice that uses client certificates. 
The program is going to be used by different clients each with their own certificate.
The client certificate is used for authentication so that clients only see their own data.
So every call to this webservices must be with their specific keystore.

Axis2 is used to generate the client side code. 
I have found this piece of code to set a SocketFactory to an specific instance of the stub.

```
int x = 9443;
Protocol authProtocol;
authProtocol = 
      new Protocol("https",
                   setPrivateKey(keyStoreFileName,keyStoreType, keyStorePassword),
                   x
                  );
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER, authProtocol);
```

And the SocketFactory would then be

```
private static SSLSocketFactory setPrivateKey
  (String keyStoreFileName,
   String keyStoreType,
   String keyStorePassword
  ) 
  throws FileNotFoundException, 
         KeyStoreException, 
         IOException, 
         NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
         CertificateException, 
         UnrecoverableKeyException, 
         KeyManagementException
  {
    // Load the key store: change store type if needed
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFileName);
    try {
        ks.load(fis, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) { fis.close(); }
    }
    // Get the default Key Manager
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
       KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());   
    kmf.init(ks, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
     X509KeyManager origKm = (X509KeyManager)kmf.getKeyManagers()[0];
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(new KeyManager[] {origKm }, null, null);

    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```

With the following imports

```
import com.sun.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import com.sun.net.ssl.X509KeyManager;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ProtocolSocketFactory;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
```

I get the message that X509KeyManager and SSLContext are deprecated.
Even the code from this [link](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/contrib/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java?view=markup)
(which I found trhough the offical AXIS2 documentation on the topic) uses this deprecated code.
Secondly this code uses SSLSocketFactory while the protocol expects a ProtocolSocketFactory.

What is the replacement for X509KeyManager and SSLContext? 
And how to get from a keystore to a ProtocolSocketFactory?
Or is there a better way.

Used AXIS2 1.6.2
Java 5
Tool jdeveloper 10.1.3

edit 22-01-2013
The webservice that is being called belongs to a different organisation and I have no control over the server side of webservice.

The "used by different clients" are different users of our software. That is located at 1 central point.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "used by different clients" means different deployments. In this case, is it really necessary to choose the right keystore programmatically? Would it be possible to use multiple different keystores (each for one client) and let the application server/servlet container handle the client certificates?
For example for Apache Tomcat this could achieved setting `CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keystore=<the keystore filename>"` before starting the server. You then create the client WS as usual for simple http web services without authorization. Tomcat handles the SSL connection with client auth using the certificate in a completely transparent way.

Comment: The webservice is of a different organization. So I don't have any controle over the server side of the webservice.
And with clients I mean different users of our software that is located at 1 central point.

Comment: The approach I described applies to web service clients, no need to change the server side of the web service. But in the case, that you mentioned you seem to need to use rampart (http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/). A example can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136512/axis2-rampart-client-self-signed-certificates The truststore is specified by using the "javax.net.ssl.keystore" environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

The blog http://shivendra-tripathi.blogspot.com/2010/11/enabling-ssl-for-axis2-service-and.html gives under the heading Approach 2 the answer to your problem:

“Apache commons provide facility which allows us to customize the SSL socket factory responsible for creation of secure socket. By customization I mean ability to use user truststore/keystore in SSL handshake. To achieve it we need to extend SecureProtocolSocketFactory interface. In our custom socket factory implementation user refer its Keystore/Truststore against default keystores.
Apache commons provide a reference implementation class named AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory for this purpose.

This class takes Truststore/Keystore as argument to constructor which will be referred later while initiating SSLContext. SSLContext is used to create SSL Socket Factory.
In your axis2 client code you need to add following:
Protocol authhttps = new Protocol ("https", new AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory (new url("keystore URL"), "pwd", newURL("truststore URL"), "pwd"), 443);”

Use the authhttps object in the line that starts with stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConsta...